# Add value from dropdown to html attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, html-select

I'm trying to add a dropdown value to a attribute in the table below. But it doesn't seem to work using the `.attr()` from [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

This is the jquery:

```
$("#datasize").change(function(){ 
        var element = $(this).find('option:selected'); 
        var myTag = element.val(); 

        $('#filterTable1').attr('data-page-size' , myTag); 
    });
```

This is the html:

```
    <select id="datasize">
        <option value="10">My option</option>
        <option value="20">My other option</option>
    </select>
    <table class="footable" data-page-size="" id="filterTable1">
        <thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </thead>
   </table>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It does work already - http://jsfiddle.net/jxXsN/

Comment: It does work... It's a library that's conflicting :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("#datasize").on('change', function(){ 
        $('#filterTable1').attr('data-page-size' , this.value); 
    });
});
```